# d3 Grouped Chart 1st level not looping

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js, nested-loops

I am trying to create a grouped chart like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051.

This is my code so far:

```
    var width = "100%";
    var height = "96vh";


    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                   .append('svg')
                   .attr('width',width)
                   .attr('height', height)
                   .style("border", "2px solid black");

    var canvasWidth= parseInt(canvas.style("width"));
    var canvasHeight= parseInt(canvas.style("height"));

    var y0  = d3.scaleBand()
                .paddingInner(0.1)
                .rangeRound([0, canvasHeight]); 

    var y1 = d3.scaleBand()
               .padding(0.08);  

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()    
              .range([0, canvasWidth]);

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["blue","green"])

    d3.csv("data.csv", data =>{
        console.log(data);

        //inner columns domain
        var keys = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1,4); 

        data.forEach(d=>{
            d.properties = keys.map(key => {return {key:key, value:+d[key]}})
        });

        //console.log(data[1].properties);

        var max = d3.max(data, d=>d['Open rate'])

        x.domain([0,max]);
        y0.domain(data.map(d => d.Industry));
        y1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0,y0.bandwidth()]); 

        console.log(x(data[1].properties[1].value))

        console.log(keys);


        var all= canvas.append("g")
                  .selectAll("g")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", d => {"translate(0, "+ y0(d.Industry) + ")"}); 
        //console.log(y0(data[1].Industry));          

        all .selectAll("rect")
            .data(d=>d.properties)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("y", d=>y1(d.key))
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("height", y1.bandwidth())
            .attr("width", d =>x(d.value));



    });
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKlYI.png) is how the results look right now. (I don't know how else to show the results, as I am working on a local file)

All the bars are being mapped but the y-translation of the chart group : `.attr("transform", d => {"translate(0, "+ y0(d.Industry) + ")"});` is not happening.

This is the corresponding html (to show that everything looks fine except the y-translation):

```
    <svg width="100%" height="96vh" style="border: 2px solid black;">
    <g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="175.42504409171076"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="23.790123456790127"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="98.05291005291006"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="256.26807760141094"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="44.326278659612"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="125.09700176366843"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="247.15696649029985"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="37.81834215167549"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="110.7072310405644"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="179.7636684303351"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="33.118165784832456"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="133.19576719576722"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="241.58906525573192"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="42.373897707231045"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="126.90476190476191"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="187.9347442680776"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="38.10758377425044"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="146.71781305114638"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="185.04232804232805"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="35.4320987654321"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="138.5467372134039"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="259.23280423280426"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="38.90299823633157"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="108.5379188712522"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="120.97530864197532"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="20.825396825396826"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="124.30158730158732"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="210.78483245149914"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="28.634920634920636"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="98.1252204585538"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="266.39153439153444"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="36.516754850088184"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="99.06525573192239"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="246.9400352733686"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="43.820105820105816"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="128.35097001763668"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="200.01058201058203"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="23.42857142857143"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="84.74779541446209"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="287"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="34.998236331569665"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="88.29100529100529"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="180.70370370370372"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="30.298059964726637"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="121.19223985890655"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="234.93650793650795"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="32.17813051146385"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="98.99294532627866"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="185.18694885361552"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="29.502645502645503"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="115.26278659611992"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="185.04232804232805"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="27.76719576719577"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="108.61022927689595"></rect>
      </g>
      <g>
         <rect y="1" x="0" height="8" width="179.47442680776015"></rect>
         <rect y="10" x="0" height="8" width="29.430335097001766"></rect>
         <rect y="19" x="0" height="8" width="118.51675485008819"></rect>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you post a few rows of the data as well? It'd be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transform function should return a string, but the curly braces are confusing the arrow function...

```
> (d => "Hello, " + d)("World!")  // without braces
'Hello, World!'

> (d => {"Hello, " + d})("World!")  // with braces
undefined

> (function(d) {return "Hello, " + d;})("World!")  // function
'Hello, World!'
```

I suspect the arrow function is trying to build an object to return, but the syntax is wrong (no key: val pair) -- so it's returning `undefined` instead. If you remove the curly braces, or use a function, it should work as expected.